# Forward a certain website to a different IP locally

Tags: networking, hosts

So what I'm trying to do, is when someone wants to visit a site like

www.illegalsite.com

I want it to redirect back to google, or a set IP address.

I dont have a DNS server or anything.

Adding this:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/9bP4cQ4.png]

To /etc/hosts but it didnt work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect 'illegalsite.com' site to a local Ip address, add the following line in `/etc/hosts`

```
194.249.214.55 illegalsite.com www.illegalsite.com
```

Comment: @Nephilim if this answer is helpful to you please click on the up arrow and if it resolved your problem please accept this answer and mark green. thanks